# Create a UIButton with (or without) memory

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uibutton

I'm trying to add a UIButton with code (not Interface Builder).

Some examples say you MUST alloc and release memory for the button.

Others use buttonWithType and magically create a button without alloc'ing any memory at all.

How is that possible?

(Both seem to work fine.)

Which of the 2 methods do I want to use... and when?   Are there some huge benefits to 1 method or another?

*PLEASE* don't tell me to just go "read the docs".   The docs are the REASON I am here.  They rarely seem to explain things without leaving out tons of 'missing info'.

Answer (score 10):

`buttonWithType:` **does** use memory, but it is `autoreleased`. This means that it will be `released` at some point in the future. So `[UIButton buttonWithType:]` is equivalent to `[[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:] autorelease]`.

You can use either method, depending on whether you want to be explicit or not about releasing.

Answer (score 3):

Both works. The `+buttonWithType:` method is a convenient method, which is similar to

```
[[[UIButton alloc] initWithType:type] autorelease];
```

Since it is already `-autorelease`'d, you cannot `-release` it.

For built-in buttons (e.g. rounded rectangular, info buttons, etc.), you must use `+buttonWithType:` because there is no other ways to create them. Otherwise, both choices are fine.

Comment: For "rounded rectangular" you must use +buttonWithType.....................................
Really?  I didn't know that either.  So there *ARE* reasons/places to use 1 method... and not the other?

Comment: @Jill: Yes, but that's *not* because of memory stuff. BTW, `-initWithType:` does not exist, in case someone wonders.

Comment: `-initWithType` is not exist.

Answer (score 0):

There are two memory management method in Cocoa: **reference count** and **autorelease**.

According to the [Memory Management Policy in Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html),

> You own any object you create
>
> You create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy).

**buttonWithType** has none prefix as mentioned above, so you have not own of the button created by **buttonWithType**. In fact, **buttonWithType** use the anther method, **autorelease**, to release the created button.