# what is the difference between this two lines?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uibutton

```
UIButton *btn=[[UIButton alloc] init];
```

and

```
UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

What is the difference between these two declarations or are both the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[UIButton buttonWithType:...]
```

creates an **autoreleased** object (which still needs memory).

```
[[UIButton alloc]init]
```

creates an object which is not going to be autoreleased. you have to release by yourself!

have a further look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281966/create-a-uibutton-with-or-without-memory).

And more about [memory management](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

Answer (score 2):

The first one will assign a `UIButton` object to `btn`. You are responsible for releasing it when you are finished, since you `alloc`ated the memory.

The second one will perform the same action, but the object will be autoreleased, meaning that you do not have to call `release` explicitly, as the operating system will perform that action when necessary.

Note: The `UIButtonType` is also different.

Answer (score 1):

First one gives you a not autoreleased `UIButton` with a `buttonType` of `UIButtonTypeCustom`

Second one gives you an autoreleased `UIButton` with a `buttonType` of `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect`